# The field body_markdown is not returned for comments

Tags: bug, api-v2, comments

Using the method *questions-by-ids* to get the comments on a particular question, I do not get body_markdown returned despite it being selected in the filter.

Here is the [test query](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=154&filter=!*l7rj3QGnUkcu1YH(13AR(_P&site=math&run=true) to reproduce the bug.

Selecting *body* instead of *body_markdown* returns the comments in HTML, as expected. However, if I
select **both** *body* and *body_markdown* in the filter, neither is returned.

Comment: Confirmed, even for fresh comments (still editable).  I wonder if this was meant to be a write-only property for the comment object?

Comment: [Confirmed.](http://stackapps.com/q/4975/29015)

Comment: Confirmed.  I get very random behaviour where sometimes I can get the body_markdown if I also tick the body, but then the reply_to_user field disappears (like with a `*12j3(Y0Qul7i_*BcSBRoq3` filter)

Comment: Actually the same query, namely  `curl -G -d site=unix -d sort=creation --data-urlencode 'filter=*12j3(Y0Qul7i_*BcSBRomM' 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/22565/comments'` from one run to the next returns `body_markdown` fields sometimes and not other times.

Comment: So did this start up again, or has it ***always*** been that way?  I find that when I have this problem, if I add `body` to the filter, run it once, then I'll get both `body` and `body_markdown`, then if I remove `body`, I'll get `body_markdown` in the next run but not any subsequent to that.  It's seems like a weird caching rule or something but surely others have experienced this?