# Filter doesn't consistently return comment bodies

Tags: bug, api, comments, filter, api-v2.2

I've been trying to set up a filter I can use with `/questions/{id}/answers/` (using the UI at [this link](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-questions)), which returns the following fields:

```
answer:
    answer_id
    body_markdown
    comments
    creation_date
    owner
    score
    share_link

comment:
    body_markdown
    link
    owner

shallow_user:
    display_name
    user_id
```

The problem is `body_markdown`. No matter what I do, the filters don't return it. Sometimes they do, if I switch off some of the other fields, but even then, if I actually want to use the filter in a request, it breaks again.

For example, I created the filter: `!)ayn4w2btvFUpB1d6.o.BKKcUINGse1wa_ZUcP23R8RvI` .
It should contain all of the above fields and, [if I query it at `/filters/{filter}`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/read-filter#filters=!)ayn4w2btvFUpB1d6.o.BKKcUINGse1wa_ZUcP23R8RvI&filter=default&run=true) it reports to include all the fields I want.

But if I actually use it, either [testing it in the docs](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-questions#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=40562&filter=%21%29ayn4w2btvFUpB1d6.o.BKKcUINGse1wa_ZUcP23R8RvI&site=codegolf&run=true) or [sending an actual query](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/40562/answers?page=1&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=votes&site=codegolf&filter=%21%29ayn4w2btvFUpB1d6.o.BKKcUINGse1wa_ZUcP23R8RvI) the `comment.body_markdown` field is not present.

What's going on here?

Comment: Just found [this bug report](http://stackapps.com/q/4840/29015) from 3 months ago. Feel free to close this one as a duplicate, but I don't want to delete it, because it contains a bit more information for reproducing the bug.

Comment: This Q is better. Close the other one as a dupe of this one. (As shown on SO, multiple times, age is no factor on which Q gets called duplicate.)

Comment: Was this ever resolved? (ping @BrockAdams) It's getting really frustrating for me, having to burn two API requests whenever I want to get a question + comments or answer + comments.

Comment: @TastesLikeTurkey, no it is not resolved.  The devs are very lackadaisical about API bugs.  Try cross-posting a bug report on [metase].

Comment: @BrockAdams Thanks. [Done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301090/filter-doesnt-consistently-return-comment-bodies).

Comment: Still an issue for me.   I find that when I have this problem, if I add `body` to the filter, run it once, then I'll get both `body` and `body_markdown`, then if I remove `body`, I'll get `body_markdown` in the **next** run but not any subsequent to that. It's seems like a weird caching rule or something but surely more have experienced this than the few users here?