# Get everything touched by a user?

Tags: support, questions, users, answers, comments

I'm trying to figure out the best way to compile all "post threads" (Questions and all related Answers and Comments) where a specific user owns any of the `{Question, Answer or [a comment on either the Q or A]}`.

It seems like there's probably a more efficient way than the combinations of methods I've been trying, for example:

> ```
>  (1) get `question_id`'s from `users/xxx/questions`
>  (2) get `question_id`'s from `users/xxx/answers`
>  (3) get `combined list` of `post_id` + `post_type` from   
>   - `users/xxx/comments` and `users/xxx/mentioned`,
>     - then split into 2 post-types:  
>     - if post_type="question" then it's a question_id  
>      - remaining `post_id`'s are `answer_id`'s: 
>         (4) get `question_id`'s from `answer/{ids}`
> ```
>
> Finally, combine all `question_id`'s into unique list and query them again, for selected fields from questions/answers/comments.  *(body, dates, counts, userids, username, wrapper).*

Is there a better way to do this?

It doesn't help that I've been intermittently fighting with the ["missing comments" problem](https://stackapps.com/q/4840/50270).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since some users might exhaust your quota, for such a set of data, this might be a better job for [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

---

In your API approach, not sure why you are getting question id's from answer id's.  You can give `/answers/{ids}` a filter to make it return: username, tags, and title for the answer's question -- which may be all you're after?

---

But in/with the API, I would:

1. Use [the `/users/{ids}/timeline` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/timeline-on-users#pagesize=100&ids=50270&filter=default&site=stackapps&run=true) to get question, answer, and comment id's on one swoop.
   As a bonus, comment text is already included in the `detail` property for comments.
2. Optionally, query `/users/{ids}/mentioned` too.
3. Feed the answer post id's, 100 at a time, to `/answers/{ids}` to get further details if desired.
4. Feed the question post id's, 100 at a time, to `/questions/{ids}` to get further details if desired.

Comment: I need to do this programmatically, hence the API, unless there's a way to do this from SEDE?  I'd much rather retrieve 50,000 rows at a time instead of 100.  Meanwhile, ` /users/{ids}/timeline` may be a quicker way for me to retrieve my list of "every question a user has touched".  For example, if "User X" came to this page and added a comment anywhere, I's now want to include *not only the comment* in the dataset for "User X", but also the source Question, all of its Answers, and all comments on the question, or any of its' answers.

Comment: I don't foresee a problem with API limits, because 10k calls should be enough to get 7 @JonSkeet's/day.  (I hope he doesn't mind being a unit of measurement!) The average user has 10 posts and 26 comments.

Comment: JonSkeet has over 2767 *pages* of data (based on wanting to get the parent question for every comment, answer, and mention).  That's over a quarter of your bandwidth and would take 20 to 50 minutes to fetch if you somehow didn't get rate limited.

Comment: Data Dump data can be fetched programmatically from Google's BigQuery -- which has an API.

Comment: Also, to reiterate, the `/timeline` route solves your "intermittent missing comments problem", in this case.

Comment: *`...BigQuery -- which has an API`* very interesting...  I'm going to check that out, although I eventually need to get this working with the realtime data.

Comment: If you fetch the bulk with BigQuery, then you can limit the SE API calls to just that data that occurred since the last data dump.

Comment: Great idea, thanks. Out of curiosity, on what did you base the estimate for fetch time? Is there a standard avg you use?

Comment: For me, if I try a long series of sustained fetches at more than about 2 per second, I start getting backoffs.  Limiting to 1 per second seldom sees problems.  [Theoretically, if you want to push it, you could get 2767 pages in 2 minutes](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle).